# Recursive call - getting stack overflow

Tags: java, recursion

I am working on a project for school in Java. We are writing Hu's tree algorithm. I have written a recursive method to set the level of each node dependent upon the adjacency matrix. When I run the code I am getting a stack overflow error.

My full code is below. I am having problems with the level() method. Please help

```
package husalgo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class HusAlgo 
{
    private static int numJobs;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        input();       
    }

    public static void input()
    {
        int level = 0;
        int root = 0;

        numJobs = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter number of jobs: "));
        int machines = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter number of machines: "));        
        int[] begin = new int[numJobs];
        int[] end = new int[numJobs];

        for (int i = 0; i < numJobs - 1; i++) 
        {
            begin[i]  = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the begining arc for job " + (i + 1) + ": "));  
            end[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter ending arc for job " + (i + 1) + ": "));            
        }



        int[][] adj = adjMatrix(begin, end, numJobs);
        level(adj, root, level);

    }

    public static int[][] adjMatrix(int[] begin, int[] end, int numJobs)
    {
        int[][] adj = new int[numJobs][numJobs];

        for (int i = 0; i < numJobs; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numJobs; j++) 
            {
                adj[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numJobs; i++) 
        {
            adj[begin[i]][end[i]] = 1;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(adj));
        }



        return adj;

    }

    public static void level(int[][] adj, int root, int l)
    {

        int[] lev = new int[numJobs];
        lev[0] = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numJobs; i++) 
        {
            if (adj[i][root] == 1) 
            {
                lev[i] = l + 1;
                level(adj, i, l + 1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(adj));
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're getting a stack overflow, it must mean that your test for the end of the recursion is wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question to at least tag it better. What programming language are you using? Also, use your debugger. The test `adj[i][root]==1` looks suspicious...

Comment: If `lev` is an integer, how can you do `lev[0] = 0` -- that expects `lev` to be an array.

Comment: sorry I changed it to make sense and didnt change that. It should be levArray

Comment: Keep in mind the code is incomplete and I am a student.

Comment: LOL someone down voted me but I have researched and I have changed my code a hundred times. I do not understand what I am doing wrong yet people still judge because they are perfect. Why do people not help yet down vote posts. Do they think it is funny?

Comment: @Amarian: people expect you to be able to use the debugger (or add debugging prints) and understand what is happening: draw the picture of your call stack on a board, and keep it evolving.

Comment: I think, you should to append some recursion limit, like `l > MAX_L` or anything else. Your recursion hasn't own limit.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch OK thank you. I will keep this in mind. I have debugging on my end but didn't think to bring here. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out:

```
package husalgo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class HusAlgo 
{
    private static final int numJobs = 5;
    static int[] lev = new int[numJobs];
    private static final int[][] adj = new int[numJobs][numJobs];

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int lev = 0;
        int root = 0;

        int numJobs = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter number of jobs: "));
        int machines = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter number of machines: "));        
        int[] begin = new int[numJobs - 1];
        int[] end = new int[numJobs - 1];

        //Grab input for the begining and ending arcs
        for (int i = 0; i < begin.length; i++) 
        {
            begin[i]  = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the begining arc for job " + (i + 1) + ": "));  
            end[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter ending arc for job " + (i + 1) + ": "));            
        }       

        //Setup adjacency matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < numJobs; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numJobs; j++) 
            {
                adj[i][j] = 0;
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numJobs - 1; i++) 
        {
            adj[begin[i]][end[i]] = 1;
        }

        level(root, lev);      
    }

    public static void level(int root, int l)
    {        

        for (int i = 0; i < numJobs; i++) 
        {
            if (adj[i][root] == 1) 
            {
                lev[i] = l + 1; 
                level(i, l + 1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Levels: " + Arrays.toString(lev));
    }

}
```

This is my working code. When I made the numJobs global I was also using for array lengths. I moved the variable to input and pulled the adj[][] argument out of the recursive method. When the recursion occured it was creating another instance of the array and causing stack error. Thanks for !help...